# Static member initialization for template classes

Tags: c++

I want to enable or disable some features from a class by deriving it from one type or another. Everything worked fine until I introduced another level of indirection for deriving condition.

Example:

```
template<bool EnableB>
struct Traits1
{
    static const bool BEnabled = EnableB;
};

template<bool EnableB>
struct Traits2
{
    static const bool BEnabled;
};

template<bool EnableB>
const bool Traits2<EnableB>::BEnabled = EnableB;

struct A{};
struct B : public A{};

template<typename Traits>
struct C : public std::conditional<Traits::BEnabled, B, A>::type
{
};


int main()
{
    C<Traits1<true>> c1; //OK
    C<Traits2<true>> c2; //error C2975: '_Test' : invalid template argument for 'std::tr1::conditional', expected compile-time constant expression
}
```

I wouldn't have any problem initializing my `Traits` inside class, but only integral types can be initialized inside class...

Can you please explain why this problem appears? Is a problem with my compiler(VS2010) or this is normal behavior?

Comment: `bool` is considered an integral type. You do realize that you are initializing one bool in one case and not initializing it in the other? The error message also points to a type that is not in the question... why don't you post the exact code that is giving you the error or else **reproduce** it in a smaller example and use that?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Why downvote? In Traits2 I initialize BEnabled outside the class. This is legal in C++ for integral types. Also the error message is for THIS example, _Test is from std::conditional. Please read the code and test it before downvote...

Comment: Initializing inside or outside of the class is valid in C++, but the first creates a compile time constant and the other need not. The comment on initialization is for *but only integral types can be initialized inside class..* which is true, but is a restriction that does not apply to your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine using GCC 4.7 (on Mac OS).  I'm going to go with it being a compiler shortcoming.  Maybe try GCC on Windows if you're up to it.